# "It is snow everywhere." OR "It is snowy everywhere."

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

An expert is talking about microplastics on BBC, and she tells about how we are surrounded by plastic. She says:

**"...and you know, it is plastic, it is plastic everywhere."** [BBC-microplastic](https://www.bbc.com/reel/video/p0h7vcts/we-inhale-a-credit-card-s-worth-of-microplastics-each-week). (see: 4:06-4:10) (I also checked the subtitles.)

Since this sentence is correct, I wonder if can we similarly say:

**"It is snow everywhere."** when you wake up and open the curtains and see that everthing is covered with snow.

Or should we say:

**"It is snowy everywhere."**

Which one would be idiomatic?

Comment: What do you think "It is plastic everywhere" means? What part of speech do you think "plastic" is? Why do you think it is the same as "It is snow everywhere"?

Comment: It is the same, because both "plastic" and "snow" are nouns.

Comment: People should take it easy with downvotes. This was hard due to the word "everywhere". ELL are not native speakers which is why they ask questions...

Comment: You could also say "Everything is covered in snow" or "The entire landscape is snow-covered" or, more dramatically, "There is snow as far the eye can see"

Comment: This question would be better if it was edited to include the context that @Lambie found (that the woman in the BBC video is referring specifically to her computer), which was necessary to correctly get to the heart of the misunderstanding. Someone *might* colloquially say "it's plastic everywhere" referring to the environment around them, but it would be a bit awkward and not really correct.

Comment: I think she actually said "... it's plastic. **There's** plastic everywhere!" But it's so quick that it's hard to tell. That would mean the captions are incorrect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, "it's snow everywhere" is not right for what you see outside your window. Here's why.

The woman in the BBC video says this:

*I'm sat in front of my computer right now, and I'm looking at the different components of my computer and **it's** plastic. It's plastic everywhere*.

In this case, she means: the computer is plastic ***all over***. Meaning: **All of it is plastic**.

**it** here **is not** a dummy *it* as in: It's snowing outside. "it" is a pronoun that stands for the computer.

When you see a lot of snow outside your window, you might typically say: There's snow everywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, as for what she said, I am quite sure she is saying "It is plastic, it is plastic everwhere." Just check the subtitles.

Comment: @yunus A minor thing which I have now changed but it does not change the main point I made. it=the computer. Not a dummy it, as in: It's snowing. everywhere is sometimes used to mean all over something. He had red paint everywhere, all over himself.

Comment: Thanks Lambie, your answer was to the point. It specifically answered what confused me. I wondered whether "it" in the sentence was a dummy subject or not. That is why I thought I might apply the same structure to such similar sentences. And now, I understood, I can't apply it, because it stands for the computer specifically. So, I accepted your answer.

Comment: @yunus  Anyway, she uses the contraction it's. Okay, well, I'm glad we solved that one! :) I think it might have been the "everywhere" for "all over" that threw you off.

Comment: This is a good answer for helping the OP learn how English works. But at the risk of confusing the OP, I (as a native English speaker) would add that "It's snow everywhere" is also a valid sentence to describe what one sees outside. It's a little more idiomatic in some sense, and harder to analyze why it's correct, but a native speaker could definitely say it and not be wrong.

Comment: I can think of a context where someone might naturally say "It is snow everywhere." Say you have a fantasy novel where someone says, like, "Beware the frosty curse of Algidus!", and someone else says "What's that?", and gets the response, "It is—it is snow everywhere! Blizzards, from pole to pole!!"

Answer (score 4):

The first sentence is not correct. If you want to say that it's still snowing, you can say:

> It is snowing everywhere.

But I don't think that was your intention.

Similarly, your second sentence could indicate that it's snowing, but doesn't express the thought you described:

> It is snowy everywhere (means it is snowing everywhere).

Look at what you put in the first line of your question:

> *When you wake up and open the curtains and see **there is** snow everywhere.*

**That** is what you should say:

> There is snow everywhere.

There are many other ways to express the same thought, such as:

> Everything is covered in/with snow.
>
> There's a blanket of snow everywhere.

Comment: I edited the question. This native speaker on BBC says: "It is plastic everywhere." (see: 4:06-4:10) https://www.bbc.com/reel/video/p0h7vcts/we-inhale-a-credit-card-s-worth-of-microplastics-each-week

Answer (score 2):

[Snow](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snow) is a noun, so you can say

> It is snow. - *The stuff that we are looking at is snow.*

but you can't say

> It is snow everywhere.

... because 'it' defines what you are looking at / pointing at, and 'everywhere' clashes with 'it'.

Instead, you should say

> There is snow everywhere. - *Everywhere that you look, there is snow.*

[Snowy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/snowy) is an adjective, meaning full of or covered in snow, so you can say

> It is snowy everywhere. - *Everywhere that you look, it is snowy. (covered in snow)*

Comment: I edited the question. This native speaker on BBC says: "It is plastic everywhere." (see: 4:06-4:10) https://www.bbc.com/reel/video/p0h7vcts/we-inhale-a-credit-card-s-worth-of-microplastics-each-week

Comment: In the BBC video, what she actually says is "I'm looking at my computer and it's plastic". This is grammatically correct. She then adds "plastic everywhere", This is not a sentence: it's just for emphasis, and it doesn't fit grammatically with what she has just said. She may be alluding to the Rime of the Ancient Mariner: "water, water everywhere". That's not grammatical either, but poetic licence applies.

Comment: No, she says "It is plastic, it is plastic everwhere." Just check the subtitles. And re-listen it. She says -as a full sentence- "It is plastic everywhere."

Comment: @yunus It's plastic, it's. not it is. Now you can check them.

Comment: @Lambie, :) :) :) :)

Comment: Maybe it just colloquial: In German one can say "Es ist überall Schnee" (*It is snow everywhere*), and everybody would understand, while strictly speaking it's not correct ("Überall liegt Schnee" might be).

Comment: "It's snowy (everywhere)" sounds to me to be suggesting that it's currently snowing, not that there's snow on the ground.

Comment: @Lambie "It's" here is short for "it is", so what's your point? It's the same.